# How to execute a findAndModify in Restheart?

Tags: restheart

I'm running some tests with Restheart, but can't find how to execute a findAndModify in it via curl or httpie. Has anyone done that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RESTHeart all write requests have upsert semantic, in other words they all end up with a findAndModify operation.

If you need to update several documents with one single request, you can use the bulk write request, example:

```
PATCH /db/coll/*?filter={"qty":{"$lte":20}} {"$inc": {"qty": 1}}
```

Note the **wildcard** * as the document id in the resource URI.

Have a look at [write requests](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/JQBGAQ) documentation section for more information.